# PPL Process : EvtOpenSession for remote EvtLog failing with ErrorCode 1749 (Security Context is Invalid) in PPL Service Process

Tags: winapi, win32-process

EvtOpenSession for remote EvtLog failing with ErrorCode 1749 (Security Context is Invalid) in PPL Service Process

From the PPL process service we are trying to connect with DomainControllers EventLogger thru  EvtOpenSession() API but its failing with error ErrorCode 1749 (Security Context is Invalid).

Its working perfectly fine with Non-PPL services.

Comment: You need to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example. So that community can make research on your question and solve your problems. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you solved it so far? or do you have any other ideas?